# Reading a File, Replacing Items In List Then Writing To That File

Tags: python

Doing an exercise in Automate the Boring Stuff With Python that is a simple MadLibs program.

Need to read a string from a file, convert it to a list, replace certain words (NOUN, VERB, etc.) with user input, then join that list and write the new list to a file.

My program reads, collects user input and recognizes the words, but unable to swap input for existing word... have tried List Comprehension, enumerate, and simply setting word == response. TIA

```
path = ('/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/MadLibs/ML1.txt')

MadLib = open(path)

content = MadLib.read()
content = 'The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB.'
content = content.split()
MadLib.close()



for word in content:
    if word == word.upper() and len(word) > 1:
        word = word.replace('.','')
        response = input(f"Enter a {word} \n")
        [response for word in content if response]

content = ' '.join(content)

ML1 = open('ML1.txt', 'w')
ML1.write(content)
ML1.close()

MadLib = open(path)
output = MadLib.read()
MadLib.close()

print(output)
```

Comment: `[response for word in content if response]` creates a new list that is immediately garbage collected because no name ("variable") refers to it. If you want to replace, say, `ADJECTIVE` in `content`, you already know how to use the `replace` function, so I don't see what's stopping you. Also, your current code will iterate over individual characters in `content`.

Comment: replace works for strings but not lists: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Please decide if `content` is a list or a string. The code in your questions suggests that it's a string

Comment: Did you intend to immediately overwrite what you read from the file on line 9? Additionally, when you iterate a string (`for word in content`), you're iterating _each character_, so `len(word) > 1` will always evaluate `False`.

Comment: edited this so it's clearer. i included the actual string for content bc the file path is useless to anyone else trying to run the program/test it out... to clarify: line6 reads a string from the .txt file in the file path, line7 splits this into a list for iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar remarks as Ahndwoo. But I would not recommend to use `content.replace` because the replacements can interfere in the search. Below is another version with a second list to be on the safe side.

```
content = 'The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB.'
content = content.split()

new_content = []

for word in content:
    if word == word.upper() and len(word) > 1:
        word = word.replace('.', '')
        response = input("Enter a replacement for {}: ".format(word))
        new_content.append(response)
    else:
        new_content.append(word)

new_content = " ".join(new_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already used the function you need in your code: use `replace()` again!

```
content = 'The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB.'.split()

for word in content:
    if word == word.upper() and len(word) > 1:
        word = word.replace('.','')
        response = input(f"Enter a {word} \n")
        content = content.replace(word, response, 1)
```

Adding the `1` as the third argument of `replace` means that it will only replace the first instance it finds of that word. So if you have multiple NOUNs or ADJECTIVEs, it will only replace one of them, instead of all.

Of course, this won't work if the intention was to replace all the words with the same response. If that's what you intended to do, then you need to actually remake your list:

```
content = 'The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB.'.split()

for word in content:
    if word == word.upper() and len(word) > 1:
        word = word.replace('.','')
        response = input(f"Enter a {word} \n")
        content = [response if w.replace('.', '') == word else w for w in content]

content = ' '.join(content)
```

This will work, for that case, except that it will still prompt you for the second, third instance of each type of word, even though they won't be used. You could create a set where you add words that have already been replaced, and check the current word against it so the user is not prompted for them.